# Why starting a non-responsive service from a QThread blocks the main GUI?

Tags: winapi, pyqt, locking, python-3.5, qthread

PyQt 5

Python 3.5

I have a Windows service that cannot be started for a few seconds after it has been stopped. If you try it returns error 1053. When I try to start it during this "unresponsiveness period" with win32serviceutil. StartService() from a QThread (with a worker inside), StartService() runs for about 20 seconds and finally returns error 1053. The problem is that despite StartService() being run in a separate thread, it will also block the main GUI thread. Here's my sample code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from win32serviceutil import StartService


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    done = pyqtSignal("PyQt_PyObject")

    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.func(*self.args)
        except Exception as e:
            result = e
        self.done.emit(result)  # Pass function return.
        self.finished.emit()


Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("window.ui")


class TestApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        # Hide What's This button and show only close button.
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.text_box.returnPressed.connect(self.run_thread)

        self.worker = None
        self.thread = None

        self.go_button.clicked.connect(self.run_thread)

    def run_thread(self):
        if self.text_box.text().strip():
            # Start service from generic worker inside a QThread.
            self.worker = Worker(StartService, self.text_box.text().strip())
            self.thread = QThread()

            self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

            self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
            self.worker.done.connect(self.done)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
            self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
            self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

            self.thread.start()
            self.busy(True)  # Activate progress busy mode.

    def busy(self, status):
        end = 0 if status else 100  # 0 is busy progress bar, 100 is inactive.
        self.p_bar.setRange(0, end)

    @pyqtSlot("PyQt_PyObject")
    def done(self, result):
        self.busy(False)  # Deactivate progress bar.

        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            title = "Error"
            msg = str(result)
            icon = QMessageBox.Critical
        else:
            title = "Started"
            msg = "Done"
            icon = QMessageBox.Information

        # Show message box with result.
        dialog = QMessageBox(self)
        dialog.setWindowTitle(title)
        dialog.setText(msg)
        dialog.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        dialog.setIcon(icon)
        dialog.exec_()


def main():
    program = QApplication(sys.argv)

    svc_stopper = TestApp()
    svc_stopper.show()

    sys.exit(program.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the window.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>230</width>
    <height>120</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Start Service</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="go_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>76</x>
      <y>13</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start Service</string>
    </property>
    <property name="autoDefault">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QProgressBar" name="p_bar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>211</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="value">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="textVisible">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="text_box">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>211</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderText">
     <string>Service display name</string>
    </property>
    <property name="clearButtonEnabled">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>go_button</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Any reason why you need to send `StartService` from the main thread? Why not call it directly in the worker thread and see if that helps. I think the service my be forced to stay in the thread it is initialized. `self.func = func` might be enough for it to initialize. Might also be worth while changing `Worker(QObject)` to a `QThread` for the test.

Comment: I tried both suggestions (calling `StartService` from the `Worker` and from a subclassed `QThread`) but got the same problem: The GUI locks until `StartService` returns.

Comment: Python is not really multithreaded. Could be your winapi call is keeping the Python GIL. Subprocesses would be the way out. Or there is a problem with your code.

Comment: @Trilarion How would you suggest to use multiprocessing for this?